# Principle of Virtual Displacements using integration by parts

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm just starting with [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=iFNDDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=statics+and+influence+functions+--+from+a+modern+perspective&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiomb2F7d_YAhVF6WMKHUkCBVIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=statics%20and%20influence%20functions%20--%20from%20a%20modern%20perspective&f=false) to get a better grasp of FEM from a mathematical perspective, so my multivariable calculus is a bit rusty. While I intuitively understand what is mean by the work of 2 forces being zero (Eqn 1.9), I'm having problems with the integration by parts.

The relevant equations state that for functions $u$ and $\delta u$, if the function $u(x)$ satisfies the differential equation (Eqn. 1.11):

\begin{equation}
-EAu''(x) - p(x) = 0, 0 < x < l,
\end{equation}

then holds
\begin{equation}
\int_0^l(-EAu'' - p)\delta u dx = 0,
\end{equation}

or after integration by parts assuming that $\delta u(0) = \delta u(l) = 0$,

\begin{equation}
\int_0^l\frac{N\delta N}{EA}dx = \int_0^lp\delta udx,
\end{equation}

where $N = EAu'$ is the normal force

How does the integration by parts work to get the last equation? If the integration by parts formula is:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^lf(x)g'(x)dx = \left[f(x)g(x)\right]_0^l - \int_0^lg(x)f'(x)dx
\end{equation}

I get that the $f(x)g(x)$ component will be zero when evaluated (based on the assumptions for $\delta u(0)$ and $\delta u(l)$, but I'm missing which components are evaluated as f and g for the integrals.

Comment: the $\delta$ symbol is something with a lot of meaning, what does it mean here? is $\delta u$ really just another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating by parts yields
$$
\int_0^\ell \left( -EAu''(x) \right)\delta u\;\mathrm dx\\
=-EA\delta u(\ell)u'(\ell)+EA \delta u(0)u'(0)+EA\int_0^\ell u'(x)\delta u'(x)\;\mathrm dx
$$
with your assumption that $\delta u(0)=\delta u(\ell)=0$ implying that the boundary terms vanish, and the integral is just
$$
EA\int_0^\ell u'(x)\delta u'(x)\;\mathrm dx
$$
renaming $N$ for purposes unclear to me in the above gives you back your expression (with $\delta$ being treated as constant it seems).

Next if
$$
-EA\int_0^\ell u''(x)\delta u(x)\;\mathrm dx-\int_0^\ell p(x)\delta u(x)\mathrm dx=0
$$
as was assumed, then our work gives you that 
$$
EA\int_0^\ell u'(x)\delta u'(x)\;\mathrm dx=\int_0^\ell p(x)\delta u(x)\mathrm dx
$$